# Change font size of headers in SCRBOOK?

Tags: header-footer, fontsize, scrbook

First of all, I am not very familiar with LaTeX. I did write a paper with it before but I somehow only assembled my settings and packages to my needs. However, now I am working on a new paper and I would like to use my old document as a template to not go through that entire process again.

Anyways, I am facing difficulties because my prof wants a different style than the other time.
The headers of the chapters and sections should all be font size 14 (which one is equivalent in LaTeX?) and start immediately after the previous text.

I am using KOMA script (SCRBOOK). So how would I do that?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Can you give us a minimal example? Usually, chapters start a new page. Maybe it would be easier to user `scrartcl` for a paper since it is not actually a book? What is the default font size? What other options are you using which affect the size of document elements? Koma has a whole bunch of options which might affect this.

Answer (score 2):

[image: haledScrbookFontsize]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section,indent=0pt]{chapter}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont\bfseries} 
\sectionfont{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont\bfseries}
```